# PersistenceUtil signer information doesn't match in unit tests

Tags: java, jpa, junit, eclipselink

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run a unit test.
The error doesn't occur when I run the app under tomcat (but oddly enough it doesn't give the same error when I run tomcat from within a snapcraft installed snap).

Initial Session factory creation failed: 
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Both the unit test and the tomcat war initialise jpa using the same method which is:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public static void init(String persistenceUnitName)
{
    try
    {
        if (emf == null)
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName);
        else
        {
            logger.error("Someone is trying to initialise EntityManagerUtil a second time." 
                    + Arrays.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()));
        }

    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        logger.error("Initial Session factory creation failed: " + e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

There are two version of the class javax.persistence.PersistenceUtil imported via my pom.

One is directly found in the jar:
eclipselink-2.7.1.jar

The other is in the jar:
javax.persistence-2.2.0.jar

the second jar javax.persistence is a dependancy of the eclipselink-2.7.1.jar.

If I exclude the javax.persistence jar then the project won't compile.

Comment: weird that EclipseLink packages the javax.persistence classes in the JPA implementation jar. The normal thing to do is have a JPA provider jar and a JPA API jar. Will only lead to problems like yours, as well as class loader issues.

Comment: see also https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525457